# Problemas nas interação UI com uso de condicionantes

Tags: r, shiny, ui

Olá, bom dia!

Estou tendo dificuldades, para realizar os cálculos de variáveis do solo.
o código fica dizendo: `argument is of length zero`. O comando tem que funcionar da seguinte forma:

1 selecionar a cultura, na aba "Cultura" (`tabName="CULT_DATA"`), `selectInput(inputId="CULT"...)`.

2 Na aba "Manejo" `(tabName="MANEG_DATA")`, selecionar a opção `radioButtons("TP_MANEJ",...)`.

3 Na aba "Clima" `(tabName="WEATH_DATA")`, preencher os valores de "ETc" `textInput("ETC",...)`, e "Pe" `textInput("Pe",...)`.

4 Na aba "Solos" `(tabName="SOIL_DATA")`, caso a opção: "Dados do solo automático" estiver selecionada  `input$AUTO_SOL==T`, ele deve verificar em `input$TP_MANEJ` a opção selecionada.

Para `input$TP_MANEJ==1`, proceder os cálculos com os valores de: **CC, PMP, Da e ZE**, disponíveis nas tabelas **(CULT_F, GROUP_F, TEXTURA)**.

Para `input$TP_MANEJ==2`, utilizar os valores em `input$ETc`, e `input$Pe`.

Caso a opção `input$AUTO_SOL==F`, ele deve utilizar os dados de `input$CC`, `input$PMP`, `input$Da`, `input$ZE`, fornecidos pelo usuário.

segue abaixo o código que estou tentando corrigir:

```
shinyApp(

  ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(

      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Cultura",      tabName = "CULT_DATA"),
        menuItem("Clima",        tabName = "WEATH_DATA"),
        menuItem("Solo",         tabName = "SOIL_DATA"),
        menuItem("Manejo",       tabName = "MANEG_DATA")
      )),

    dashboardBody(

    tabItems(

tabItem(tabName="CULT_DATA",
        sidebarPanel(
          fluidRow(
            selectInput("CULT",label="Cultura",c(paste(CULT_F$CULTURA,sep=""))),
            column(6, textInput("ZE","Z (cm):",value=0)),
            column(6, textInput("FF","Fator f",value=0))))
),

tabItem(tabName="MANEG_DATA",
        sidebarPanel(
          radioButtons("TP_MANEJ",label="Manejo:",choices=list("Solo"=1,"Clima"=2)),
          fluidRow(
            column(5, textInput("Pi","Pi (dias):",value=0),
                   textInput("H","H(horas):",value=0),
                   textInput("Eapli","EA(%):",value=0))))
),

tabItem(tabName="WEATH_DATA",
        sidebarPanel(Title="Dados do Clima",
                     fluidRow(
                       column(8, textInput("ETc","ETc (mm):",value=0)),
                       column(8, textInput("Pe","Pe (mm):",value=0))))
),

tabItem(tabName="SOIL_DATA",
        sidebarPanel(
          fluidRow(
            column(6, textInput("CC","CC (%):",value=0),
                   textInput("Da","Da (g/cm3):",value=0)),
            column(6, textInput("PMP","PMP (%):",value=0),
                   textInput("VIB","VIB (mm/h):",value=0))),
          checkboxInput("AUTO_SOL",label="Dados do solo automático:",FALSE),
          radioButtons("TEXTUR",label="Textura:",choices=list("Arenosa"=1,"Média"=2,"Argilosa"=3))),
        mainPanel(tableOutput("Dados_solos"))
)))),

server <- function(input, output) {

# Tabelas!!! no caso eu estou carregando elas usando source("tabelas"), 
# que  carregam os comandos read.csv() de cada uma

CULT_F<-structure(list(
GRUPO=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,
4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,5L),
CULTURA=structure(c(12L,20L,8L,7L,21L,26L,14L,24L,
3L,15L,13L,5L,1L,17L,18L,25L,
4L,19L,6L,2L,23L,22L,9L,11L,16L,10L),
.Label=c("Abacaxi","Açafrão","Alfafa","Algodão","Amendoim",
"Azeitona","Banana","Batata","Beterraba","Café",
"Cana-de-açúcar","Cebola","Cítricas","Ervilha","Feijão",
"Fumo","Girassol","Melância","Milho","Pimenta","Repolho",
"Soja","Sorgo","Tomate","Trigo","Uva"),class="factor")),
class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,-26L))

GRUP_F<-structure(list(GRUPO=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L),ETC=c(2L,3L,
4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,
10L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,
7L,8L,9L,10L),FATORF=c(0.5,0.425,0.35,0.3,0.25,0.225,
0.2,0.2,0.175,0.675,0.575,0.475,0.4,0.35,0.325,0.275,
0.25,0.225,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.45,0.425,0.375,0.35,0.3,
0.875,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.55,0.5,0.45,0.425,0.4)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,
-36L))

TEXTURA<-structure(list(TEXTU=structure(c(1L,3L,2L),.Label=c("Arenosa",
"Argilosa","Média"),class="factor"),COD=1:3,VIB=c(26L,
18L,12L),CC=c(16L,18L,24L),PMP=c(7L,9L,12L),ZE=c(20L,
30L,40L),DA=c(1,1.3,1.5)),class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,
-3L))


get.ETC<-function(X){ifelse(X<=2,2,
ifelse(X>2&X<=3,3,
ifelse(X>3&X<=4,4,
ifelse(X>4&X<=5,5,
ifelse(X>5&X<=6,6,
ifelse(X>6&X<=7,7,
ifelse(X>7&X<=8,8,
ifelse(X>8&X<=9,9,
ifelse(X>9,10,"ERRO_ETC")))))))))}


  observe({
    #source("IrIgA/TABELAS/TAB.R")
    #source("IrIgA/FUN/FUN.R")

    ETC<-get.ETC(input$ETc)
    CULT<-CULT_F[CULT_F$CULTURA==input$CULT,]$GRUPO
    FF<-GRUP_F[GRUP_F$GRUPO==CULT & GRUP_F$ETC==ETC,]$FATORF
    DSOL<-TEXTURA[TEXTURA$COD==input$TEXTUR,]

  })


# Tentando fazer a reação com base nas condicionantes input$MANEJO, input$AUTO_SOL

    # saída deveria ser na forma de tabela com as respostas de IRN,DTA,CTA,CRA, 
# dentre outros. Mas meu interesse é usar esses objetos nos cálculos futuros.


  SOLOS<-reactive({


    if(input$TP_MANEJO==1)
      return({
        if(input$AUTO_SOL==TRUE)
          return({
            DTA<-((DSOL$CC-DSOL$PMP)/10)*DSOL$DA                                           # Disponibilidade Total de água: DTA (mm cm^-1)
            CTA<-DTA*DSOL$ZE                                                               # Capaciadade Total de Água: CTA, (mm cm^-1) 
            CRA<-ifelse(CTA*FF>0,ifelse(CTA*FF<1,1,CTA*FF))                                # Conteúdo real de água: CRA, (mm)
            IRN<-CRA})

        if(input$AUTO_SOL==FALSE)
          return({
            DTA<-((input$CC-input$PMP)/10)*input$Da                                                          # Disponibilidade Total de água: DTA (mm cm^-1)
            CTA<-input$DTA*input$ZE                                                                     # Capaciadade Total de Água: CTA, (mm cm^-1) 
            CRA<-ifelse(CTA*input$FF>0,ifelse(CTA*input$FF<1,1,CTA*input$FF))                 # Conteúdo real de água: CRA, (mm)
            IRN<-CRA})  

        cbind(data.frame(Cultura=input$CULT,FatorF=FF),DSOL,data.frame(DTA=DTA,CTA=CTA,CRA=CRA,IRN=IRN))
      })

    if(input$TP_MANEJ==2)
      return({IRN<-round(input$ETc+0.02,0)

      cbind(data.frame(Cultura=input$CULT,FatorF=input$FF,Z=input$ZE),data.frame(IRN=IRN))})

  })

  output$Dados_solos<-renderTable({SOLOS()})

})
```

Comment: você já conseguiu resolver este problema? Caso afirmativo coloque a resposta aqui e aceite a resposta.

Comment: irei fazer isso, porém sem tempo para organizar o script, adiando que era nas condições "if", depois da dupla igualdade o valor a ser comparado tem que ficar entre aspas simples input$TP_MANEJ=='2') .